# How to restrict routes in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I have 2 types of user :

1. Admin
2. Not Admin

`Admin` will get the full-access, where `Not Admin` will only get the index.

Here are my routes

```
 Route::get('users','UserController@index');
 Route::get('users/create', array('as'=>'users.create', 'uses'=>'UserController@create'));
 Route::post('users/store','UserController@store');
 Route::get('users/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'UserController@show'));
 Route::get('users/{id}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
 Route::put('users/{id}/update', array('as'=>'users.update', 'uses'=>'UserController@update'));
 Route::delete('users/{id}/destroy',array('as'=>'users.destroy', 'uses'=>'UserController@destroy'));
```

How do I make a restriction so that `Admin` will get the full-access, where `Not Admin` will only get the access to index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your **filters.php**

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    if (Auth::user()->type == "Admin") // Change this to match your !
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
        }

    }

    else return View::make('error'); // Need to have this view !
});
```

Then try this on your **routes.php**

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'admin'),function() {

//Users
                Route::get('users','UserController@index');
                Route::get('users/create', array('as'=>'users.create', 'uses'=>'UserController@create'));
                Route::post('users/store','UserController@store');
                Route::get('users/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'UserController@show'));
                Route::get('users/{id}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
                Route::put('users/{id}/update', array('as'=>'users.update', 'uses'=>'UserController@update'));
                Route::delete('users/{id}/destroy',array('as'=>'users.destroy', 'uses'=>'UserController@destroy'));
```

Repeat for `if (Auth::user()->type != "Admin")`

Answer (score 1):

You would use a [route filter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters) that checks their permission level.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @ceejayoz answer with an example:

```
/*
 * Check if user is logged in
 */
Route::filter('auth', function(){

    if(!Auth::check()){

        return Redirect::to('login')->with('message', 'You must be logged in');

    }

});

/*
 * Check if the logged in users group name is 'admin'
 */
Route::filter('admin', function(){

    if(Auth::user()->group->name != 'admin'){

        return Redirect::to('home')->with('message', 'You do not have access to this');

    }

});


//Users must be logged in to access these routes
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'), function(){

    Route::get('users','UserController@index');

    //Users must be an administrator to access these routes
    Route::group(array('before'=>'admin'), function(){

        Route::get('users/create', array('as'=>'users.create', 'uses'=>'UserController@create'));
        Route::post('users/store','UserController@store');
        Route::get('users/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'UserController@show'));
        Route::get('users/{id}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
        Route::put('users/{id}/update', array('as'=>'users.update', 'uses'=>'UserController@update'));
        Route::delete('users/{id}/destroy',array('as'=>'users.destroy', 'uses'=>'UserController@destroy'));

    });

});
```

Comment: Why do we need only `Route::filter('admin', function(){ ... }});` , but not the **Not-Admin**, just curious.

Comment: Sorry about that, just modified

Comment: No problem. Thx for your help. Hey ! I will ask one more question which is very similar to this one, but deeper. If you have time, can you help me with that too ? Thx ahead man.